# Geopandas - ValueError: Cannot transform naive geometries. Please set a crs on the object first

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas

Can someone please explain how this is not working?

[image]

The shapefile in question is [here](https://geoine-ine-chile.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/54e0c40680054efaabeb9d53b09e1e7a_0) and in the code its read as

```
shp=gpd.read_file("Microdatos_Censo_2017_Manzana/Microdatos_Censo_2017_Manzana.shp")
shp.crs="epsg:4326"
breakpoint()
shp=shp.to_crs(epsg=3857)## Error here
```

I just dont get what is happening. I have `Python 3.8.5`, `geopandas 0.8.1`, `pyproj 2.6.1.post1`. Not sure what other package would be important to know versions of.

Thanks!

---

Edit:

1.- Fixing link to shapefile that I had gotten wrong.

2.- It's not the same as the question that is posted as a duplicate, because as you can see on the image the print statement of `shp.crs` returns the correct crs information, not None. I have a crs defined and yet `to_crs` is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make geopandas dataframe from points, then project the gpd, got error: Cannot transform naive geometries. Please set a crs on the object first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61050942/make-geopandas-dataframe-from-points-then-project-the-gpd-got-error-cannot-tr)

Comment: Can you try using `shp = shp.set_crs(4326)` instead of the second line?

Comment: For me, your code snippet works with the linked Shapefile, using the same versions of the libraries. Can you show a complete reproducer? (full code, including imports to traceback) Also, how did you install geopandas?

Comment: Yes sorry! I had linked the wrong shapefile, I am working with 4 shapefiles so I must have gotten confused which one was the problematic one! The corect shapefile is linked now

Comment: Using `set_crs` instead of `.crs=` fixes the problem! Any reason why this might be?

Answer (score 5):

In your code:

```
shp = gpd.read_file("Comunas/Comunas.shp")
```

let you get `shp` as a `GeoDataFrame`.

Next, the line

```
shp.crs = "epsg:4326"
```

only changes the property of `shp`, but does not perform coordinate transformation on the geodataframe.

Then

```
shp = shp.to_crs(epsg=3857)
```

causes the error.

From the error messages it is obvious that the command that causes error requires proper `object` as its input value. The value in `epsq=3857` is wrong according to the method's signature as follows.

```
.to_crs(crs=None, epsg=None, inplace=False)
```

The proper use of this method can be:

```
.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
.to_crs(crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
.to_crs(epsg='4326')
```

For your particular dataset,
to convert the CRS of the original `GeoDataFrame` (epsg:3857), to epsg:4326, and back to original, do these steps:

```
shp_file = './data/comunas/comunas.shp'  #(on my machine)
comunas0 = gpd.read_file(shp_file)
print(comunas0.crs)                      #{'init': 'epsg:3857'}
comunas0.plot()
```

[image: epsg3857]
(image of `comunas0`)

```
comunas4326 = comunas0.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
print(comunas4326.crs)                   #{'init': 'epsg:4326'}
comunas4326.plot()
```

[image: epsg4326]
(image of `comunas4326`)

```
comunas3857 = comunas4326.to_crs(epsg='3857')  #back to original CRS
print(comunas3857.crs)                   #{'init': 'epsg:3857', 'no_defs': True}
```

**EDIT**

Additional plots using new shapefiles (as updated by OP).

epsg:3857

[image: new3857]

epsg:4326

[image: new4326]

Comment: I am sorry but this doesnt work. I linked the wrong shp. The correct link is https://geoine-ine-chile.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/54e0c40680054efaabeb9d53b09e1e7a_0 . I am really sorry

Comment: @M.O. With the new shapefile `Manzana_2017_2.shp`, using my proposed steps also works.

Comment: Your proposed steps are the steps I had, and they didnt work for me. But using `set_crs` instead of `.crs=` makes it work. Doesnt really make sense why though since those two should be equivalent.

Comment: @M.O.But I can get the plots.

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to project LineStrings, it didn't work. I had to first project Points then create LineStrings.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30155531)